# Displaying Content in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simpleadapter

Creating a simple registration form and storing the values in database. The data stored should be displayed on Home page after user finishes registration. On home page, I created a ListView in which on a row I want to show username given by user along with a button adjacent to it and on click of that button user should able to see the registration entries on another page.

For this I tried using simpleAdapter but that I guess didn't worked or not properly programmed. I also thought to use Expandable ListView but do not know how to use it.

Please, just help me with your suggestion to display the content of the Registration on View and the how to perform a click event on button inserted in ListView.

My codes are:

**HomeActivity.java**

```
package com.nsa.project;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnDetails;
    EditText edtusername;
    ListView details;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        edtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtuser);
        btnDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndetails);
            details = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.regsdisplay);
    }


    public void displayDetails()
    {
        DataBase d = new DataBase(HomeActivity.this);
        arraylist = d.readDetails();

        //Expandable ListView
        details.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist, R.layout.mylayout, new String[] {CT.USER_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.btndetails}));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onResume();
                displayDetails();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        int groupId = 0;
        int order = 0;
        int itemId = 0 ;
        String title = "My menu";

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menu.add(title);

        MenuItem mNext = menu.add(groupId, itemId, order, " New User").setIcon(R.drawable.add_user);

            mNext.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent in = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Registration.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    return false;
                }

            });

            MenuItem mExit = menu.add(groupId, itemId+1, order+1, "Exit").setIcon(R.drawable.exit);

                mExit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        SubMenu sb = menu.addSubMenu("Create User");
        sb.add(groupId, itemId, order, "First");
        sb.add(groupId, itemId+1, order+1, "2");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, Layouts are

**activity_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/regsdisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**mylayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#CCBBAA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFAAFF"
        android:text="View Details"></Button>    

</LinearLayout>
```

**LOgcat Error**

```
 01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:160)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:563)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:378)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
01-26 23:11:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
01-26 23:11:45.684: I/Process(410): Sending signal. PID: 410 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The NSA is blocking you. `com.nsa` is a "reserved" package name...

Comment: cut down your code and post the relevant parts

Comment: @Emmanuel: It's my own package name. How it's blocking anyway?

Comment: @Raghunandan: what parts I should cut and what else you want me to post?

Comment: @Saggy you stack trace indicates something is null @ line 41 `HomeActivity.java` and indicate what is line 41. So you know what is relevant now. So remove all unnecessary codes.

Comment: @Emmanuel, you may have very fine knowledge of a domain but use it in helping other instead of making fun.

Comment: @Raghunandan : Got it! Did the same.

Comment: @Saggy what is line 41?

Comment: Its where I am setting the adapter "details.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist, R.layout.mylayout, new String[] {CT.USER_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.btndetails}));" I know something is wrong in it. Hence, I asked that shall use simplae adapter to display the format or Expandable ListView will be a wise idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListView details` is not initialized. Add the following after `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`:

```
details = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.regsdisplay);
```

The follow-up `ArrayIndexOfBoundException` comes here:

```
details.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist, R.layout.mylayout, new String[] {CT.USER_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.btndetails}));
```

There's only one `from` column name and two `to` view identifiers.

Comment: Ok I got it. But, I only want to show a button and username on ListView so, will this work? details.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist, R.layout.mylayout, new String[] {CT.USER_NAME, "View Details"}, new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.btndetails}));

Comment: No, there's no "View Details" data in the source. You don't need to map any data from the source to a static button. Just have it as is in the row layout.

Comment: Didn't get you laalto.

Comment: Just remove `R.id.btndetails` from the `to` array.

Comment: Finally, its working. I just only need to provide the textview's id in simple adapter instead and adding button in that took whole case. Thanks laalto. Now, to display content of Registration I need to code for button separately in HomeActivity.java.. is that tight?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any where you initializing `ListView details;` and you have

```
details.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist, R.layout.mylayout, new String[] {CT.USER_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.btndetails}));
```

So initialize `details`.

```
details = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.regsdisplay);
```

Also listview is in `activity_home.xml` but i do no see `EditText` and `Button` in the same.

You have Button in `mylayout.xml` not in `activity_home.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btndetails"
```

Either you posted a incomplete layout or you messed up while referencing the ids for the inflated layout.

Comment: Actually, I created this custom layout to merge the two views i.e. TextView and Button. So, I defined them in mylayout.xml and used the same in simpleAdapter at HomeActivity.java where I have defined a ListView to display the content of mylayout.xml

Comment: I have initialized the ListView details now and still encountered with the edited error in post.

Comment: @Saggy the initializing of buttons and edittext is wrong. for the arrayindexoutofboundexception laalto answer gives you the solution

Comment: @Saggywhat laalto meant was you have `new String[] {CT.USER_NAME}` single column but you have `new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.btndetails}`. you probably missed another column

Comment: @Saggy you will also end up in `NullPointerException` if you use edittext or button. This is for future reference.

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan....it's working now. Also thanks for sharing valuable knowledge for future references.